# No route matches [PATCH] "/contact.1"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to rails and struggling with the mentioned error in Rails 4.2.3 application. I am getting this error while updating a resource:

```
No route matches [PATCH] "/contact.1"
```

Here is my application code snippets:

**routes.rb**

```
resources :contacts
```

**models/contact.rb**

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  validates :number, presence:true
end
```

**views/contacts/edit.html.erb**

```
<h1> Editing Contact </h1>

<%= form_for @contact do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %><br>

    <%= f.label :number %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :number%><br><br>

    <%= f.submit "Update Contact", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

**controllers/contacts_controller.rb**

```
def edit
    @contact = Contact.find(params[:id])
end

def update
    @contact = Contact.find(params[:id])
    if @contact.update(contact_params)
        flash[:success] = "Contact Update Successfully..."
        redirect_to contacts_url
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end
```

Surprisingly the path being generated as `/contact.1` instead of `/contact/1`.

I also tried by adding `url: contact_path(@contact), method: :patch` to `form_for` but no luck.

Can anybody tell me what is wrong with the code?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't omit relevant code piece? Make a full-text search in your code for `contacts_path(`, 99% chances that you are calling `contacts_path` instead of `contact_path` somewhere.

Comment: @EugZol why would `contacts_path` return `/contact.1`?

Comment: `contacts_path(1)` will return `/contacts.1` because it's in plural form, and it's only argument is format (c.f. `contacts_path(:json)`)

Comment: @EugZol thanks for the explanation. This should result in a warning - passing an integer (or a model instance) as the format option doesn't make any sense and is probably always a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, try changing your redirect_to from "redirect_to contacts_url" to "redirect_to contacts_path". Inside your controller you should use path instead of url. So your code will be like this:

```
 def update
     @contact = Contact.find(params[:id])
     if @contact.update(contact_params)
         flash[:success] = "Contact Update Successfully..."
         redirect_to contacts_path
     else
         render 'edit'
     end
 end
```